# I get an error when executing a stored procedure in MySQL (Error Code: 1054)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| asset_id           | varchar(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lifetime           | tinyint(4)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| depreciationRate   | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| condition          | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| manufacturer       | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| plant              | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| serialNumber       | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| depreciationMethod | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| costOfPurchase     | decimal(18,0) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| serviceInterval    | decimal(18,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state              | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| assetType          | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| purchaseDate       | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| warrantyCode       | varchar(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| serviceDue         | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When I tried to use a stored procedure I created on the above table in MySQL, I get the following error:

`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'serviceInterval' in 'field list'`

The stored procedure I created is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `UpdateNextServiceDue`(IN assetId VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    DECLARE serviceInt DECIMAL(5,2);
    DECLARE performedDate date;
    DECLARE purchaseDate date;
    DECLARE nextDate date;
    SELECT `serviceInterval` INTO serviceInt FROM noncurrentasset WHERE asset_id = assetId;
    IF performedDate = null THEN
        SELECT `purchaseDate` INTO performedDate FROM noncurrentasset WHERE asset_id = assetId;
    ELSE
        SELECT `serviceDue` INTO performedDate FROM noncurrentasset WHERE asset_id = assetId;
    END IF;
    SET nextDate = DATE_ADD(performedDate, INTERVAL serviceInterval YEAR);
    UPDATE `noncurrentasset` SET serviceDue = nextDate WHERE asset_id = assetId;
END
```

Most probably, the error must be present in the stored procedure. However, I cannot find it. Can someone please tell me what's wrong here and how can I correct it.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated to your problem, I notice that in the table, `serviceInterval` is a `decimal(18,0)`, while in the stored procedure you define the `serviceInt` variable as a `decimal(5,2)`. They should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variable is `serviceInt`.not `serviceInterval`

```
...
 SET nextDate = DATE_ADD(performedDate, INTERVAL serviceInt YEAR);
...
```